# Passing Arguments from INSERT / UPDATE to Trigger

Tags: trigger, postgresql-9.2

I need a help with a trigger, this trigger I need to pass a value that comes from the queue column in the asterisk.queue table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER gerarconf
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON asterisk.fila
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE asterisk.registra_gerar_conf_fila('FILA','XXXXX');
```

In place of XXXX I need to pass the value of the queue column that came from the insert or update of the asterisk.queue table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NEW or OLD depending if you need the inserted or updated record.

[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> When a PL/pgSQL function is called as a trigger, several special variables are created automatically in the top-level block. They are:
>
> NEW
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is unassigned in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.
>
> OLD
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the old database row for UPDATE/DELETE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is unassigned in statement-level triggers and for INSERT operations.

```
CREATE TRIGGER gerarconf
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON asterisk.fila
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE asterisk.registra_gerar_conf_fila('FILA',NEW.column);
```

Comment: This does not work. Arguments to a trigger function can only be plain strings